# Javascript carousel css transition not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

hi im wondering why my css transition is not working. the carousel does the loop and and all, but my transition only works when i open dev tools and point at the element with my mouse.
heres the code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXQpNo

thanks for your help

```
var slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slide_element"));
    var i = 0;
    function test(){
        if(i === slides.length - 1){
        slides[slides.length - 1].classList.remove("displaying");
        i = 0;
        slides[i].classList.add("displaying");
         }
        else{
            slides[i].classList.remove("displaying");
            slides[i+1].classList.add("displaying");
            i++;
        }
    }
    setInterval(() => {
        test();
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Looks like it works for me without having to open dev tools, https://jsbin.com/sufejewuxe/1/edit?html,css,js,output does that work?

Comment: Nah it doesnt its really weird! but i tried the css offered by Josef and it works like a charm now :) thanks for the help tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in "slide_element" remove `display: none;` and the transition add to it (all) so it will become like this `transition: all .3s;`
and set it to absolute positioning, so your css would look like this:

```
.slide_element{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    transform: translateX(1000px);
}
```

Comment: sweet! that works, i was gonna go crazy there for a sec. thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helps, actually I ran into the same problem a couple weeks ago

Comment: oh glad to see that im not the only one that runs into problems then, and here i tought i was some kinda future bad developper or something. again thanks for the help.